# How can I configure VirtualBox so that my guest has a 1920x1080 resolution while being full screen?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, resolution

- Environment: I use VirtualBox 7.0.12. Both the host OS and the guest OS run Windows 10. VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed.
- Problem: my host has a `3840x2160` resolution. I want my guest to have a `1920x1080` resolution. How can I achieve that?
- Constraint: I don't want to lower the host OS resolution.
- Motivation: the virtual machine is lagging a bit with that `3840x2160` resolution.

---

What I've tried: I switched to the full screen mode, but I don't have the option to select `1920x1080` display resolution in my guest OS:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the VM menu in VirtualBox:

1. Disable the full screen mode (if it was enabled).
2. `View>Virtual screen>Resize to [size]` to choose a new size in pixels.
3. Select "Scale to 200%" option in the same menu.

Scaling the `3840x2160` screen to `200%` will yield a `1920x1080` resolution:

[image]